# How to change to another tab from inside of a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my html code,
what i wanna do is to give navigate from one tab to another from inside of any tab,by keeping link in it,as u can see below,but this is not happening when i try,instead nothing happens when i click links,i am unable to find any reason for this,
Pls. give me a simple solution for this,thank you, in advance.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Your content goes here for tab 1
        <a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        <a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Your content goes here for tab 2
        <a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        <a href="#tabs-3">Tab 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Your content goes here for tab 3
        <a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        <a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything urself?jQuery?

Comment: I don't fully understand. You have some tabs, and you have links within each tab that are supposed to switch to different tabs?

Comment: Is this the jQuery UI tabs widget?

Comment: Looks like it. @ABV, the jQuery UI tabs widget special-cases the links in the `<li>` elements in order to perform navigation. This behavior is not extended to links inside the content `<div>` elements, you will have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jquery example using the data tag attribute that should get you pointed in the right direction [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AdBn/2/).

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a data-tab="1" href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-tab="2" href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-tab="3" href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Your content goes here for tab 1
        <a data-tab="2" href="#">Tab 2</a>
        <a data-tab="3" href="#">Tab 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Your content goes here for tab 2
        <a data-tab="1" href="#">Tab 1</a>
        <a data-tab="3" href="#">Tab 3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Your content goes here for tab 3
        <a data-tab="1" href="#">Tab 1</a>
        <a data-tab="2" href="#">Tab 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#tabs a', function(_e) {
    _e.preventDefault()
    // Get the tab to select
    var tabToSelect = $(this).data('tab');
    // Hide all the tabs
    $('#tabs > div').hide();
    // Show the selected tab
    $('#tabs-' + tabToSelect).show();
});
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort,but dont know y it isnt working in my jsp

Comment: Are you using the same id value in multiple divs in your html? that is a no-no and can cause jQuery to fail. When using an id in the selector, it is expected that there is only 1 in the DOM.

Are there any errors in your dev console when you try to use this code?